# When i switch to another source in ListView it does'nt update

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm fairy new to Xamarin, and I trying to do a switching List. So when button is pressed, it switches to another list. I have CustomLists class which wraps all this lists and exposes ChosenList property, which gives access to list currenly being displayed. When entry in List is deleted Command property gets called

```
public ICommand DeleteTest
{
    get { return new Command<TaskRecord>((s) => OnDelete(s)); }
}
void OnDelete(TaskRecord task)
{
    List.Remove(task);
    IsUnfinishedChanged_ = !task.IsFinished;
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ChosenList"));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Deleting..");
}
```

When I delete entry in a first list (those shown at the programm start) it works fine. But in a second, ListView doesn't update for some reason

Here's my XAML code

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ChosenList}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" SeparatorColor="DimGray">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true"  
                               Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MainGrid}, 
                        Path=BindingContext.DeleteTest}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <StackLayout Padding="15,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="Large" Font="Arial"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=ShortDescr}" FontSize="Micro" Font="Arial"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Edit: ChosenList is wrapper for `ListView` to bind to

```
public List<TaskRecord> ChosenList
{
    get
    {
        return (IsAll_ ? List : Unfinished);
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Putting the whole code up here

```
private List<TaskRecord> List { get; set; }
private List<TaskRecord> UnfinishedCache_;
private List<TaskRecord> Unfinished
{
    get
    {
        if (IsUnfinishedChanged_)
        {
            UnfinishedCache_ = new List<TaskRecord>();
            foreach (TaskRecord task in List)
            {
                if (!task.IsFinished) UnfinishedCache_.Add(task);
            }
            IsUnfinishedChanged_ = false;
        }
        return UnfinishedCache_;
    }
    set { UnfinishedCache_ = value; }
}

private bool IsUnfinishedChanged_=true;
private bool IsAll_;

public ICommand ListChangeCommand
{
    get { return new Command<string>((s)=>OnListSwitch(s)); }
}
void OnListSwitch(string senderText)
{
    if (senderText == "All" && !IsAll_)
    {
        IsAll_ = true;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ChosenList"));
    }
    else if (senderText == "Unfinished" && IsAll_)
    {
        IsAll_ = false;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ChosenList"));
    }
}

public ICommand DeleteTest
{
    get { return new Command<TaskRecord>((s) => OnDelete(s)); }
}
void OnDelete(TaskRecord task)
{
    List.Remove(task);
    IsUnfinishedChanged_ = !task.IsFinished;
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ChosenList"));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Deleting..");
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public List<TaskRecord> ChosenList
{
    get
    {
        return (IsAll_ ? List : Unfinished);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to be using `ObservableCollection` for ChosenList and then changes to it will be handled by the `ListView`

Comment: Maybe I shoud try, but it still bothers me, why it works fine with one list, but don't update with another.

Comment: It is strange that you have a property called List that you are modifying but are raising the PropertyChanged event for a property called ChosenList. Either that is the issue or there are parts of your implementation you should share.

Comment: `ChosenList` it's a wrapper, made to incapsulate which list is currently active. I'll add it's code to question

Comment: Without seeing the logic to do all of this it is probably not going to be possible to give a helpful answer.

Comment: How is `IsAll_` being set and how is `Unfinished` being modified (i.e. deleted from)

Comment: Perhaps in your `OnDelete` method you will need to do the same check on IsAll_ and remove from Unfinished if IsAll_ is not true?

Comment: `IsUnfinishedChanged_` is used as dirty flag for `Unfinished`. If it is set to true, next time `Unfinished` requestd it will be recalculated. `IsAll_` set to false in constructor (meaning that when program starts `Unfinished` will be shown) and changed by the button click

Comment: You really need to put all of that code up on here

Comment: “But in a second, ListView doesn’t update” does this mean if you delete from the second list or if you delete for a second time?

Comment: From second list. My `ListView` is binded to `ChosenList` property. If `IsAll_` is false, and hence `Unfinished` is displayed, deleting works as it should, and element disapper from `ListView`. But when I switch to `All` by setting `IsAll_` to true, and delete some element, it is deleted from list, but not from `ListView`. If I switch back to `Unfinished` and then return to `All` changes are displayed correctly, but if I delete another element, `ListView` still won't update. Hope I explained it well

Comment: I get what you are trying to achieve now. The code isn't the easiest to follow but I will see if I can work out why it is going wrong

Comment: You likely need to stick a breakpoint in the OnDelete method and also in the ChosenList getter and see what gets hit when you delete something in the scenario that doesn't work